# Como validar um usuário no Active Directory através do Android

Tags: android, delphi, active-directory

Estou tentando validar usuário no Active Directory com Delphi XE7 + Android. Antes eu utilizava nas versões para anteriores para *desktop* mas agora não consigo fazer para o Android.

Comment: Está comunicando o dispositivo android com um servidor de aplicação, ou quer que o android valide direto no AD do windows?

Comment: eu preciso que ele valide direto no AD do Windows, tem como?

Comment: não conheço. Mas vai ter de pesquisar primeiro se isso é possível no Android Nativo ou se o AD permite algum service de validação global. Mas, se ele vai ter de se comunicar com o Windows para validar, porque não já implementar o micro servidor de validação?

Comment: Estou garimpando para ver se consigo conectar direto, mas se preciso for vou ter que fazer uma aplicação DataSnap e já aproveitar a situação.

Comment: Olha, pesquisando no GooglePlay encontrei este: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.bealsystems.ADUserManagerFree então, cabe saber se ele acessa diretou ou como acessa. Mas parece que não é suporte nativo

Comment: Por favor poe a url novamente ela ficou faltando e com o que esta aparecendo nao achei nada ou envia ela para o meu email, ailtonbrc@hotmail.com.

Comment: só clicar no link, ele oculta parte e poe reticencias, mas se clicar ele abre